# What is $\int\frac{\sin(at)dt}{t\log^2 t}$?

Tags: integration, number-theory, prime-numbers

Assume the following definitions:
$\pi(x)$ - fundamental prime counting function
$\vartheta(x)$ - first Chebyshev function

The context of this question is the following relationship.
$$\pi(x)=\frac{\vartheta(x)}{\log x}+\int_{3/2}^{x}\frac{\vartheta(t)dt}{t\log^2 t}$$

My question is: What is $\int\frac{\sin(at)dt}{t\log^2 t}$?

Answer (score 0):

I am sure that there is no closed form. But it's senseful to substitute $t=e^x$ ($dt=e^x dx$) so that one gets $\int\frac{\sin(ae^x)}{x^2}dx$ . Therefore it's $|\int\frac{\sin(ae^x)}{x^2}dx|\leq \int\frac{1}{x^2}dx\ $ for $x>0$.